# How can I use assert in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I need to know how can I do assertion in Selenium WebDriver. My situation is I have one edit, but on screen, but that edit button is present on some certain criteria.

So I want to check that if that button is present. It should be clicked on and it should open another child window and should perform certain actions. If that edit button element is not present on the screen, it should check the next condition which is the log off button in my keyword framework.

I have tried try and catch block and it is working fine.

Here is the code:

```
public void click_edit_childwindow2(String objectName) {

    // Store the current window handle
    String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();

    // Perform the click operation that opens new window
    try{
        WebElement elemnt = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='main']/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[6]/button"));
        elemnt.click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='main']/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[6]/button")).click();

        // Switch to new window opened
        for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
            driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
        }

        // Perform the actions on new window
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='myModal']/div/div/div[2]/form/div/div[10]/div/button[1]")).click();

        // Close the new window, if that window no more required
        //driver.close();

        // Switch back to original browser (first window)

        driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore);

        // Continue with original browser (first window)
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        driver.findElement((By.xpath("//*[@id='logoutForm']/ul/li[2]/a"))).click();
    }
}
```

But I want to do it with assert. Though try and catch is not stopping the code, but after testing execution it is showing that the test case as failed. How can I do it with assert?

I am using keyword framework in which one is class is for keyword and another is for reading an Excel file.

Comment: Which statement is throwing the exception?

Answer (score 3):

A typical Selenium setup will include a *test* framework that is attached to your project.

There are several test frameworks to use, but here are the most popular for Java:

- jUnit
- TestNG
- ...

When you have a test framework attached to your project, you could then use asserts like:

```
Assert.assertTrue(driver.getWindowHandles().size().equals(2));
```

If the assertion fails, it will fail the test script.  This is just one small example. I'd certainly do some research on how to use your test framework of choice.  Selenium out-of-the-box is designed to be agnostic to what you use. Get creative.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code:

```
Boolean isPresent = driver.findElements(By.yourLocator).size() > 0

if(isPresent == true)
{
     // Code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At first you need to check whether that button is displayed in the webpage. You can do that by this -

```
WebElement web = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='myModal']/div/div/div[2]/form/div/div[10]/div/button[1]"));
boolean bool = web.isDisplayed();
Assert.assertEquals(true, bool); // Here it will match that if that button
                                 // is present or not. If present it will
                                 // continue execution from the next line
                                 // or if it is not present the execution
                                 // stops there and your test case fails.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid *try*-*catch* by:

```
List <WebElement> editButton = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='main']/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[6]/button"));

if(editButton.size() > 0)
{
    editButton.get(0).click();
    for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
        driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
    }

    // Perform the actions on new window
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='myModal']/div/div/div[2]/form/div/div[10]/div/button[1]")).click();

    // Close the new window, if that window no more required
    //driver.close();

    //Switch back to original browser (first window)

    driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore);
}
else
{
    driver.findElement((By.xpath("//*[@id='logoutForm']/ul/li[2]/a"))).click();
}
```